# Postgres spatial index for LAB colours?

Tags: postgresql, r-tree

I have a Postgres database containing photographs and I want to let people search them by colour. I already have multiple colours (1-5) defined for each photograph, and I'm using [LAB colours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space) (perceptual colour space, defined in three dimensions: lightness plus two colour dimensions).

My question is: what is the best way to do this in Postgres? It's essentially a three-dimensional search, so should I use a spatial index?

My requirements are:

- run a bounding box search by colour (find photos with colours within distance X of colour Y).
- rank results by distance from colour X (return photos with colours closest to colour Y first)
- r-tree-like performance.

I've built a proof-of-concept using an rtree index in Python, and it's working pretty well. I'm just not sure how to replicate it using Postgres tables.

Comment: ...or maybe a multidimensional array would be more appropriate?

Comment: Have you **tried** using the rtree functionality of postgres? But note that Postgres rtree is really transactional. A read-only index in-memory will likely be faster, so if you don't need transactions, you may end up paying a high price for something you don't need.

Comment: Intuitively you'd want to store and query 3d points. But the built-in geometry types are 2d... That said, you might be able to get around the limitation considering that the color component in the Lab color space is actually the (a,b) part -- a 2d point.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of options.  PostGIS has multi-dimensional geometry types which may give exactly what you are looking for.  You could do bounding boxes over 3d points, for example.  That would be easiest.

PostGIS is a Geospacial add-on but it can be used for a large number of other things too.  What you are looking at doing is spacial even if not GIS and this may be the best tool for the job.  PostGIS would handle all your indexing needs also  including distance searches and the like.

If this is not acceptable you could write your own types.  You'd probably want to write GiST operators as well for them and there is a fairly large learning curve there.